# Connect to server without using RSA private key file

Tags: ssh

I have file contains RSA private key. I can connect to server using that file like this:

```
ssh -i private_key_file user@server -p port_number
```

How to connect to server without using -i parameter? I cannot make any changes on server (I mean changing any parameters for ssh). I want to keep private key in my ~/.ssh/ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about how to connect without typing the `-i` parameter on the command line every time, then the answer is to define it in your `~/.ssh/config` file. For example:

```
Host server
    IdentityFile        ~/.ssh/private_key_file
    Port                port_number
```

See the `IdentityFile` section of `man ssh_config`

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-copy-id` is the command to install your public key in a remote machine's `authorized_keys`, then you can access the remote machines with `ssh user@machine`

```
ssh-copy-id -i identity_file user@machine
```